# Does simics simulate the Intel Converged Security & Management Engine (CSME)?

Tags: simics

I would like to use Simics to test out Intel Atom Verified Boot & Measured Boot with Boot Guard without potentially breaking my development hardware (which would be a permanent breakage if I mis-fuse it). I believe that the initial boot block (IBB) verification and fused-key usage is done by the CSME. Is it possible to test whether the tamper-proofing of the IBB is working correctly, or will I only be able to test the main x86-side portion within Simics?

(I think also maybe if the CSME portion is not emulated then perhaps the handoff of trusted key hashes won't happen, so even the IBB won't be able to verify subsequent stages and thus it wouldn't be able to simulate Boot Guard in Simics?)

Answer (score 1):

The current public Simics Quick-Start Platform model does not include the CSME or other secure boot features.  It is a model limitation.